# Exception java.lang.RuntimeException on PlayStore Console

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play

I have a simple broadcast receiver, which will always run in the background. Testing locally on my device doesn't have any problem. In PlayStore throws below exception

Exception

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3990)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:233)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
> (ActivityThread.java:2006)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:107)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7582)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:492)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:941) Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException:   at
> android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1637)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1592)   at
> android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:669)
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService
> (ContextWrapper.java:669)   at com.app.BootBrodcastReceiver.onReceive
> (BootBrodcastReceiver.java:14)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3981)

Below implemented code BootBrodcastReceiver.java.java

```
package com.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootBrodcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
            //Service
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, intentService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent); <-line 14
        }
    }
}
```